# About 80-100 external links on a page? Should I just drop the page for SEO?

Tags: seo, links

I have a page on my website that has a bulleted list. In each bullet, there is an external link, and there are about 80-100 links (80-100 bullets) in that list.

That list links to all of the SWFs for a specific game, and it is available for my readers. The template for the page is like the following:

> [Small paragraph]
>
> **`<h2>`Title**
>
> [Small paragraph]
>
> **`<h3>`Title**
>
> - Apple: apple.swf
> - Pear: pear.swf
>
> **`<h3>`Title**
>
> - Lemon: lemon.swf
> - Banana: 492.swf

This type of formatting repeats for the entire page, and then there is a small conclusion paragraph. Note that there are 80-100 of these type of links, and they all lead outside the site.

So now I think I have two options: to edit the page completely, or to delete it (if so, that would be alright).

Comment: Are these links useful for your readers? If so, keep the page and add some more information to get a better ratio text/links.

Comment: Follow @Zistoloen's advice. I would also add mine: think long term, do not optimize for todays ranking algorithm, provide value to your users.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of SEO value If the page in question is relevant to the niche of the website then you should not drop the page, however if your site is about breeding fish and then you have a page about all the different socks you like to wear on a Sunday then it would make sense to drop the page about socks since your diluting your niche and authority.